# Reading a parquet datei from a sftp server to R

Tags: r, sftp, parquet, rcurl

I am trying to read a Parquet file from an sftp server. Or rather I'm trying to read a lot of them at different times from different folders, so I want to automate it^^.

After a lot of googling (and reading around here). I was able to connect to the sftp server over RCrul and even get to check out the folders I want to get the proper path completely automated by my script. The only part missing is to load the file in question itself.
However. As soon as I try to use getURL I get the following error:

```
Error in curlPerform(curl=curl, .opts=opts, .encoding= .encoding) : 
embedded nul in string: 'PAR1\025
```

To be sure the problem is not with the file, I manually downloaded it and opened it with arrows `read_parquet()` function, which worked fine.

The RCurl function `getURLConntent()` creates the same error.

`getBinaryURL()`, however, works and I get "something". The problem is that I now get a list of dimension [1:5068598] instead of an array with 31 columns and a length of 46899 rows.

Furthermore, the list does not only contain 0's and 1's but 2 numbers (like 50) or numbers and letters (like 9c).

I mean, I'm aware that this is because I read the file information into R in binary but I'm totally  unsure about how to fix this, or why it isn't just 0's and 1's.

From my attempt to google the problem, the nul string error could only be fixed by changing the file itself. Since I have to work with a couple of thousands of these files, I don't intend (or cannot) change each file manually to fix the problem.

Just downloading each file away from the sftp to my PC for working (over Filezilla) also seems to just ignore the problem instead of fixing it.

I also don't know how I should change the binary code to something readable. The main problem here is that of the 31 columns of the file, some are chars, some int, some num, etc. So how can I retransform the binary data into a version it would be if I load it in using arrows `read_parquet()` function?

I'm looking for a solution all day already and by this time I feel like I'm rather running in circles than anything else, so help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unless you can provide us with an example input file, it might be tedious to solve this for you. I would try to download the file directly to disk (see `curl_download()`) and then open the file with `read_parquet()`. You can create temporary files with `tempfile()`.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid that was a case. Sadly, I'm not allowed to give out an example file. 
I will try to download them as tempfiles and see if that works (Perfomance isn't the most important part). Thanks for the answer, I will get back to it, if I know if it worked.